# BIRT how to get table name?

Tags: javascript, report

In my report design's layout I have a label, table and HTML button.
How do I get values from tables, labels, etc. using the HTML button's OnClick event?
The table and label can't be accessed easily using "elementname".getValue(); Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your code so far or create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: my rptdesign just contains a label element, table element(with data) and an HTML button. I just want know how to access the data from the table and label using the HTML button.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this solution can be modified to how your actual table structure looks like, and what actual information you need. You can do this many different ways, but this solution utilizes [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to get the label element and also the 'td' cells from a Table and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for styling. You can see a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rplute/7qwc3ujt/) here that I made to visualize this. If it doesn't fit your needs, I would suggest looking at the jQuery API to modify how exactly you should get the data you need.

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <label id="label">This is my Table</label>
    <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Row</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
              </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>John</td>
                 <td>Carter</td>
                 <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td>Peter</td>
                 <td>Parker</td>
                 <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Rambo</td>
                <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="button" id="getInfo" class="btn btn-primary">Get Info</button>

    <br/>
    <p>Your Results Object once you hit Get Info button</p>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <!-- Get jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
// This solution uses jQuery
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // declares an object literal named 'results' to save future results
    // declares an array literal named 'tableData' to save table data
    var results = {},
        tableData = [];

    // this executes once you click 
    // the HTML button with ID '#getInfo'
    $('#getInfo').click(function() {

        //loop through each 'td' cell which has information
        $('td').each(function() {
            var value = $(this).text();
            tableData.push(value);
        });

         // assign the label to object 'results' with property label
         results.label = $('#label').text();

         results.tableData = tableData;

         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = 
                       JSON.stringify(results);  

    });

});
```